# Outlook add-in - save as dialog (saving files) and external links

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing outlook web add-in (contextual) where user would be able to download specific files. The problem I am facing right now is that I can not force save as dialog inside Outlook for desktop (in web it works fine).
So consider following simple html:

```
<a href='/files/test.pdf'></a>
```

when i click on it inside Outlook (desktop) add-in - nothing happens.
If I specify `target='_blank'` - Outlook opens empty modal window (IE11 i suppose) with that URL and nothing happens (sometimes it even forces outlook to crash and restart, notices on multiple PCs):
[image]
I have noticed, that if href's domain is the same as add-in's domain, then it tries to open it in this popup window, but if domain is different - new tab opens in default browser.

My question would be - is it possible to call save As dialog inside Outlook for desktop? and if not - is it possible to open link in new default browser's tab if URL's domain is the same as add-in's domain?

P.S. I have tried official example https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-JavaScript-FileDownload#get-the-filesaver-library, but it does not work. Probably something has changed with new version of outlook.

P.P.S. I tried on two PCs - both with latest version of Office 365, but one was running Windows 10 18xx version, another was running 1909 version. On first PC such problem does not exist - all links with target=_blank open in new tab of default browser; on win version 19xx - problem occures. After updating 18xx to 19xx - problem appeared. So this must have something to do with windows update...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating another domain, which points to location where add-in is hosted. When i need to open new tab in default browser from add-in I specify second domain.

For example: add-in is hosted on myaddin.azurewebsites.net, then we create custom domain myaddin.com. In add-in manifest I use myaddin.azurewebsites.net, everywhere where I have target=_blank links i use `<a href="https://myaddin.com/..." target="_blank"></a>`